# WooCommerce: Getting active product filters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In a WooCommerce product loop we can alter the loop by adding `?pa_{attribute}={value}` to the URL.
I am trying to create a custom product filter and I need to know which filters are active at the moment, so I can create a function to alter the URL without errors.

Is is possible to output active WooCommerce filters into an array?

Comment: use  echo current_filter(); , to get the info about current running filter.

Comment: This is to output current PHP filter. I am trying to find out which are active **product filters** (eg. `pa_size`)

Comment: you mean which attributes are selected in option for variable products or something else?

Comment: Say you have your WooCommerce products at the url `/shop/`. Then, if you change the URL to `/shop?pa_color=red`, WooCommerce will output only products that have `red` as the `color` attribute. This is what I am trying to store in an array (or get a list of these active `pa_` filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the listing according to filter using `pre_get_posts` filter hook.

Paste the below code in your current active themes **functions.php** file:

```
 function filter_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {

   if(is_shop()){
    $filter_term = $_GET['pa_color'];
    if (isset($filter_term ) && !empty($filter_term )) {
        $wp_query->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'pa_color',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $filter_term ,
                'include_children' => true,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: `$filter_term = $_GET['pa_color'];` was enough for me to check if a filter was active. Thank you very much!