# Getting current active product filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

There is a widget called `Active Product Filter` in WooCommerce, I couldn't find a way to override it's designed so I tried making my own;

```
function abc_active_filter(){
    $queryData = array();
    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryData);
    $active_filter = '';
    foreach($queryData as $key => $value){
        $active_filter = $active_filter.'<div><a href="'.remove_query_arg($key).'">CLIK TO REMOVE - </a><span>'.$key.'</span><div>';    
    }
    
    if(sizeof($queryData) > 0){
        $active_filter = '<h3>Active Filter</h3>'.$active_filter;
    }
    
    return $active_filter;
}
add_shortcode('csx_active_filter', 'abc_active_filter');
```

This will output the query key of the current URL, for example;

- `min_price`,
- `filter_size`

whereas using the widget `Active Product Filter` the output is;

- `Min Price $589`
- `Large`

is there a way to achieve the output the same as the `Active Product Filter`? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480109/woocommerce-getting-active-product-filters) the same question with me but the accepted answer is far different from what I'm trying to achieve and the one who asked the question is only looking for active filters by checking the query key.

Anyway, with the following code, I can achieve the same output of `Active Product Filter`;

```
if($key === 'min_price'){
    $active_filter = $active_filter.'<div><a href="'.remove_query_arg($key).'">CLIK TO REMOVE - </a><span>Min Price '.$value.'</span><div>';
}else if($key === 'filter_size'){
    $active_filter = $active_filter.'<div><a href="'.remove_query_arg($key).'">CLIK TO REMOVE - </a><span>'.$value.'</span><div>';
}else if .... and so on...
```

The problem is, filters are dynamic and I don't know all of them and it will take a lot of lines of codes to put them in conditional statements.

Comment: `WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();` This will return array of active product filters. Try printing it out and see if the result is what you need. `print_r(WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes());`. The problem is you are using `remove_query_arg('the query key')`, I'm not sure if the `WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes()` contains the query key.

Comment: @Polar - Interesting! But the `min_price` and `max_price` is not included in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();](https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/WC_Query/get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes/php-wc_query-get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes-method-examples.html), simply print its value and see if the result is what you need.

```
print_r(WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes());
```

Otherwise, I wouldn't recommend to reinvent the wheel. You can override the widget by extending the class of [WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters.html#14).

In your `functions.php`, insert the below code. You can change its layout, elements depending on what design you wanted.

```
class Your_New_WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters extends WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_layered_nav_filters';
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Display a list of active product filters.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'woocommerce_layered_nav_filters';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'Active Product Filters', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->settings           = array(
            'title' => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'The Active filters', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Output widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     * @param array $args     Arguments.
     * @param array $instance Widget instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
            return;
        }

        $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();
        $min_price          = isset( $_GET['min_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['min_price'] ) ) : 0; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
        $max_price          = isset( $_GET['max_price'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['max_price'] ) ) : 0; // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
        $rating_filter      = isset( $_GET['rating_filter'] ) ? array_filter( array_map( 'absint', explode( ',', wp_unslash( $_GET['rating_filter'] ) ) ) ) : array(); // WPCS: sanitization ok, input var ok, CSRF ok.
        $base_link          = $this->get_current_page_url();

        if ( 0 < count( $_chosen_attributes ) || 0 < $min_price || 0 < $max_price || ! empty( $rating_filter ) ) {

            $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

            echo '<ul>';

            // Attributes.
            if ( ! empty( $_chosen_attributes ) ) {
                foreach ( $_chosen_attributes as $taxonomy => $data ) {
                    foreach ( $data['terms'] as $term_slug ) {
                        $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomy );
                        if ( ! $term ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        $filter_name    = 'filter_' . wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $taxonomy );
                        $current_filter = isset( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ? explode( ',', wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ) ) : array(); // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
                        $current_filter = array_map( 'sanitize_title', $current_filter );
                        $new_filter     = array_diff( $current_filter, array( $term_slug ) );

                        $link = remove_query_arg( array( 'add-to-cart', $filter_name ), $base_link );

                        if ( count( $new_filter ) > 0 ) {
                            $link = add_query_arg( $filter_name, implode( ',', $new_filter ), $link );
                        }

                        echo '<li class="chosen"><a rel="nofollow" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Remove filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( $min_price ) {
                $link = remove_query_arg( 'min_price', $base_link );
                /* translators: %s: minimum price */
                echo '<li class="chosen"><a rel="nofollow" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Remove filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Min %s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) ) . '</a></li>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.
            }

            if ( $max_price ) {
                $link = remove_query_arg( 'max_price', $base_link );
                /* translators: %s: maximum price */
                echo '<li class="chosen"><a rel="nofollow" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Remove filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Max %s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $max_price ) ) . '</a></li>'; // WPCS: XSS ok.
            }

            if ( ! empty( $rating_filter ) ) {
                foreach ( $rating_filter as $rating ) {
                    $link_ratings = implode( ',', array_diff( $rating_filter, array( $rating ) ) );
                    $link         = $link_ratings ? add_query_arg( 'rating_filter', $link_ratings ) : remove_query_arg( 'rating_filter', $base_link );

                    /* translators: %s: rating */
                    echo '<li class="chosen"><a rel="nofollow" aria-label="' . esc_attr__( 'Remove filter', 'woocommerce' ) . '" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $rating ) ) . '</a></li>';
                }
            }

            echo '</ul>';

            $this->widget_end( $args );
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your `functions.php`, insert the below code again. This will unregister the default widget and replace with the new one above where your custom design or layout exist.

```
function your_function_for_overriding_widgets() {
    unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters' ); //unregistered the default widget
    register_widget( 'Your_New_WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters' ); //register your new widget
} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'your_function_for_overriding_widgets' );
```

Comment: Wow! Exactly as what I wanted! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Woocomerce has a native Widget, that in code is called `WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters`.

---

[A response by @Polar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63225602/11447191) explains how to replace the native widget with a customize version using PHP.

---

As alternative you can output the native `WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters` and overwrite it with custom CSS.To output you can do this

```php
the_widget( "WC_Widget_Layered_Nav_Filters" );
```